# Selenium IDE : how to handle popup when popup name is dynamically generated

Tags: popup, selenium-ide

How to handle popup when name is dynamically generating. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if it's just a new tab or window, just using

selectPopUp will do the trick.  Once you're done verifying what you want on the popup, then

close | |
then 
selectWindow | null |

to get back to the main window.

Comment: Thank You so much.. Klendathu. Its very helpful for me

Comment: this helped me too